# LOOKUP in another sheet with default to a third sheet

Tags: google-sheets, find, vlookup

I am trying to find a solution for my problem, using Google Spreadsheets. I have three sheets:  `Ergebnis`, `Aufträge` and `Leads`.

The formula I put in `Ergebnis` should check `Aufträge` Column A for a string present in Column A of `Ergebnis` and if that string is found, return it. If not found, it should just give the content of `Leads` C45.

Here is what I use:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(FIND(A2, 'Aufträge'!$A$2:A)), !C2, VLOOKUP(A2, 'Aufträge'!A2:A, 'Aufträge'!B2:B))
```

Comment: Alright sorry for my bad explanations.

Sheet names are: "Aufträge", "Leads" and "Ergebnis".

Row A is A:A
Row B is B:B

With VLOOKUP I get the error: "Function VLOOKUP parameter 3 expects number values. But 'Einrichten Groß' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number."
So apparently VLOOKUP can only return numerical values and no strings.

Comment: Ok, I do not fully understand this.

So here is what I tried to complete your formular, that I put in Row 3 of "Ergebnis": =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3, 'Aufträge'!A:A, 1,0), false), Leads!C3, VLOOKUP(A3, 'Aufträge'!A:A, 1,0))

It tells me: "Did not find value 'Hand-Werk' in VLOOKUP evaluation.". 'Hand-Werk' is the name of the lead that is in A3 (and also in Leads!A3).

Comment: Ok, so this almost works: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2, 'Aufträge'!A:B, 2,FALSE), Leads!C2)

In 5 out of 10 cases it gives the correct values. Only sometimes, when the VLOOKUP value should be given (so Aufträge!B is the correct value) it still gives the value of Leads!C...

Comment: Ok, my mistake. Content was somehow damages. Works fine now!
RESOLVED

Answer (score 0):

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A45, 'Aufträge'!A:A, 1,0), Leads!C45)

Works best for this problem.